# In Hibernate using Lazy loading instead of eager loading

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which the user can register products and productImages. Now there are 3 tables, User, Product, ProductImages. It is not always necessary to pull all the productImages until and unless the user explicitly goes into the product, where there is a modal, and the user can then select the images to load.

So I thought of using LazyLoading instead of EagerFetching. But I get lazyLoadException with that. So I opened a session manually in both Product and ProductImages, and I get  a ObjectNotFound Exception. The problem is, productImages has a foreign key relation with product, so I must save product first before saving its images, and that is where I am having the problem. Kindly suggest me how to use lazy load in this situation. Error log and code goes below :

Error log :

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.WirTauschen.model.ProductImage#1150]
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:253)
com.WirTauschen.dao.ProductBasicDaoImpl.updateProduct(ProductBasicDaoImpl.java:50)
```

Controller :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/product/addimages", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addProductImages(@RequestParam("productImages") MultipartFile[] uploadedFiles){

    if(uploadedFiles != null && uploadedFiles.length>0) {
        for (MultipartFile uploadedFile : uploadedFiles) {
            try {
                if (!(uploadedFile.isEmpty())) {
                    imagesList.add(uploadedFile.getBytes());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "image failed to upload";
            }
        }
    }
   return "done";
}



@RequestMapping(value="/product/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductBasic productBasic,Model model){
        model.addAttribute("product", new ProductBasic());
        productBasic.setProductimage(productprofileimage);
      int productid = productBasicService.addProduct(productBasic);
        ProductBasic productBasic1 = this.productBasicService.getProductById(productid);
            for (int index = 0; index < imagesList.size(); index++) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    productBasic1.setProductimage(imagesList.get(0));
                }
                ProductImage productImage = new ProductImage();
                productImage.setProductimage(imagesList.get(index));
                this.productImageService.addProductImage(productBasic1, productImage);
            }
            productBasicService.updateProduct(productBasic1);
           imagesList.clear();
        productprofileimage =null;
        return "redirect:/product/show";
    }
```

ProductDAOImpl :

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public int addProduct(User user, ProductBasic productBasic) {
// I was using getSessionBefore with Eager, it worked, thought of trying openSession
        session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        user.getProductBasics().add(productBasic);
        productBasic.setUser1(user);
        session.save(productBasic);
        System.out.println("Returned product information is"+productBasic.getProductid());
        session.flush();
        //session.close();
        return productBasic.getProductid();
    }

 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateProduct(User user,ProductBasic productBasic) {
        logger.debug("Editing product information");
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
      //  User user1 = (User) session.get(User.class,id);
        user.getProductBasics().add(productBasic);
        productBasic.setUser1(user);
        session.saveOrUpdate(productBasic);
        session.flush();
    }
```

ProductImageDAOImpl :

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addProductImage(ProductBasic productBasic,ProductImage productImage) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            productBasic.getProductImageSet().add(productImage);
            productImage.setProductimageupload(productBasic);
            productBasic.setImagecount((productBasic.getImagecount()+1));
            session.merge(productBasic);
            session.saveOrUpdate(productImage);
            return true;

    }
```

The controller code shouldn't contain that much service side information, but this is just an attempt to make sure it works..I have defined LazyLoading in model, I can post the code if required, kindly tell me what am I doing wrong. Any pointers are welcome. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It looks like the cascade type is an issue. could you please past the entities and their relations here. Usually if you set the cascade type to `ALL` this issue will be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension to my comments

1. Remove the saveOrUpdate above.
2. Change the cascade type to `ALL`

PS: You got exception at UpdateProduct method. but you hve posted code for addProduct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess cascade type ALL was what I was missing, fixed some bugs. Thanks.